# How do you make a update idempotent in a primary key in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this error:

SQL Error [23505]: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "name_pkey"
Detail: Key (status_id, type)=(0, 1) already exists.

When I execute this update script:

```
update schema.table_name
    set type = '1'
    where status_id in ('AT', '0', '1',);
```

Comment: There is already a row in the table with status 0 and type 1, and you have a unique key that forbids duplicates. How do you want to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary key is on `(status_id, type)`, which means that you already have rows for one more more of the following pairs:

```
AT    1
0     1
1     1
```

So, the update doesn't work.  You can ignore the key by filtering out potential conflicts:

```
update schema.table_name t
    set type = '1'
    from (values ('AT'), ('0'), ('1')) v(status_id)
    where t.status_id = v.status_id and
          not exists (select 1
                      from schema.table_name t2
                      where t2.status_id = t.status_id and t2.type = '1'
                     );
```

This simply ignores the update that would have occurred.

Comment: `UPDATE` doesn't support `on conflict`